# unable to get related table field data using select_related django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

my products model

class Products(models.Model):
pName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="Product Name")
cat_id = models.ForeignKey(ProdCat, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, verbose_name="Category")
subCat_id = models.ForeignKey(ProdSubCat, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, verbose_name="Sub Category")
type_id = models.ForeignKey(ProdType, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, verbose_name="Type")
brand_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, default=1, verbose_name="Brand")
pImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProductsImage', default='noimage.jpg')
weRepair = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="We Repair")
weRecycle = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="We Recycle")
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")

> Blockquote

using `select_related` i got the query what exactly i need. but i unable to figure out how to see any field or all field of related tables.

```
prod = ProblemProductBind.objects.all().select_related('prod_id')


>>> print(prod.query)
SELECT "repair_problemproductbind"."id", "repair_problemproductbind"."prob_id_id", "repair_problemproductbind"."prod_id_id", "repair_problemproductbind"."A_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."B_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."A_buying_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."B_buying_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."A_ISmash_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."B_ISmash_price", "repair_problemproductbind"."isLCD", "repair_problemproductbind"."askQuote", "repair_problemproductbind"."time_stamp", "products_products"."id", "products_products"."pName", "products_products"."cat_id_id", "products_products"."subCat_id_id", "products_products"."type_id_id", "products_products"."brand_id_id", "products_products"."pImage", "products_products"."weRepair", "products_products"."weRecycle", "products_products"."time_stamp" FROM "repair_problemproductbind" INNER JOIN "products_products" ON ("repair_problemproductbind"."prod_id_id" = "products_products"."id")
```

ProblemProductBind

```
class ProblemProductBind(models.Model):
prob_id = models.ForeignKey(ProblemList, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, verbose_name="Problem")
prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Products, models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, verbose_name="Product Name")
A_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="£ We Offer A")
B_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="£ We Offer B")
A_buying_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="A We Buying £")
B_buying_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0, verbose_name="B We Buying £")
A_ISmash_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="A ISMASH OFFER £")
B_ISmash_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0, verbose_name="B ISMASH OFFER £")
isLCD = models.BooleanField(default=False)
askQuote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Uploaded at")

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('prob_id', 'prod_id')
    verbose_name = 'Product Problem Pricing'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Product Problem Pricing List'




prod = ProblemProductBind.objects.all().select_related('prod_id')

>>> prod
```

<QuerySet [<ProblemProductBind: screen of IPhone 6s | Update at: 2021-06-10 12:26:12>]>

> > > prod.pImage
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pImage'

Comment: Can you add your models and an example of how you are going to use this data (where you want to see the fields)?

Comment: thank you, i need return "products_products"."pImage" field which is on join table

Comment: Well if `prod_id` is the FK field to `products_products` then you do `prod.prod_id. pImage`

Comment: prod.prod_id
NameError: name 'prod_id' is not defined

Comment: I was just guessing at what it might be. You need to include your models to get help here.

Comment: you answered actually, its done. thank you mark